# Prove that $1, f, f^2, f^3, \ldots$ form an orthonormal basis for $H^2$ if and only if $f(z)=\lambda z$, where $|\lambda|=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded analytic function in the unit disc. Prove that $1, f, f^2, f^3, \ldots$ form an orthonormal basis for $H^2$ if and only if $f(z)=\lambda z$, where $|\lambda|=1$. Please help me proving

Comment: It would really help when you rewrite the definitions what did you try ?

Comment: don't know, but try the normal part, it must be hard to have $\int |f|^{2n}=1$. Immediately $|f|≤1 \Rightarrow \vert f \vert = 1$